# UseContext not updating all the components

Tags: reactjs, use-context

TestContext.js

```
 import { createContext } from 'react';

const CheckoutDrawerContext = createContext({
  showDrawer: false,
  toggleCheckoutDrawer: () => {},
});

export default CheckoutDrawerContext;
```

TestComponent.jsx

```
export default function TestComponent() {

  const checkoutDrawer = useContext(CheckoutDrawerContext);

  function placeOrder() {
    console.log(checkoutDrawer.showDrawer)
      checkoutDrawer.toggleCheckoutDrawer()
    };

  return (
    <div className="cart-drawer__summary">
     <div></div>
      <button type="button" className="order-button" onClick={placeOrder}>
      submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

TestComponent1.jsx

```
export default function TestComponent1() {

  const checkoutDrawer = useContext(CheckoutDrawerContext);

  function placeOrder() {
    console.log(checkoutDrawer.showDrawer)
      checkoutDrawer.toggleCheckoutDrawer()
    };

  return (
    <div className="cart-drawer__summary">
     <div></div>
      <button type="button" className="order-button" onClick={placeOrder}>
      submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

App.js

```
export default function App() {
  const [showDrawer, setShowDrawer] = useState(false);

  const toggleCheckoutDrawer = () => {
    setShowDrawer(!showDrawer);
  };
    return(
      <Router>
    
    <CheckoutDrawerContext.Provider value={{ showDrawer, toggleCheckoutDrawer }}>
        <Route path="/test" exact component={TestComponent}/>
        <Route path="/test1" exact component={TestComponent1}/>
    </CheckoutDrawerContext.Provider>
        
    </Router>
    );
  }
```

steps:
open http://localhost:3000/**test**,
click submit button,
console.log prints false,
open http://localhost:3000/**test1** in a different tab,
click submit button,
console.log prints false (**why it is still false. had changed the value in the TestComponent?**)

Then added console.log after calling "checkoutDrawer.toggleCheckoutDrawer()" like below,

```
 function placeOrder() {
    console.log(checkoutDrawer.showDrawer)
      checkoutDrawer.toggleCheckoutDrawer()
    console.log(checkoutDrawer.showDrawer)
    };
```

Now the console.log prints false false. (**Why console.log after checkoutDrawer.toggleCheckoutDrawer() also prints false?**)

Comment: where is your reducer? How you are updating context?

Comment: The first problem is that state and contexts are NOT shared between tabs, unless a shared worker is used to synchronize the data, so you would have to provide `<Link to="/test1"> Go To /test1</Link>` to see the data synchronized between `TestComponent` and `TestComponent1`